# How can I see a report of my AWS Bounced emails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have an application that automatically sends thousands of emails per hour using Amazon Web Service's Simple Email System (SES).

How/where can I view a report of email bounces?

**EDIT:**
Below @Neil shows how I can setup SNS to email me about bounced emails. But is there any way I can see a report of Bounced emails in the past? Going forward is there a way I can see a bounce report/table instead of getting an email notification every time an email bounces?

Comment: It has been [long time wanted](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=118508) but there's no built-in feature for now

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Please post this comment as a an answer so that I can mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: It's 2023. Still not solved, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been [long time wanted](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=118508) but there's no built-in feature for now.

I suggest you push on this thread so Amazon gives more info about the roadmap to integrate this feature

Answer (score 1):

You can configure AWS to email you via SNS.  [See here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html)

Comment: Is there any way I can see a report of Bounced emails in the past?

Going forward is there a way I can see a bounce report/table instead of getting an email notification every time an email bounces?

Comment: PLease input the steps to have AWS send email via SNS; right now this is a 'link only' answer, which means if the information contained in the link moves, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure SES to send bounces (and complaints, and even deliveries) to an SNS endpoint.

From SNS, you can configure different subscribers:  email, http(s), or a couple other options.  The interesting option is Lambda.  Create a Lambda end point, and then write a simple function that inserts the information you want to track into DynamoDB.

This might cost you a few cents/month, but you have control over what you're recording and how to access it.